# Entity Framework: hidden connection strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `B.dll`, I want to create `APP_A` and reference `B.dll`.

`B.dll` contains `XXEntities`. If the `APP_A` needs to use `B.dll`, the `app.config` must add a connection string named `XXEntities`.

[image]

I want to hide the connection strings in `app.config`.

Attention : B.dll can't be changed

Comment: [Encrypt connection string in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760048/encrypt-connectionstring-in-entity-framework-first-code)

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to encrypt the connection string in app/web.config. This is the standard way for .NET application to hide some sensitive information from the client to expose via configuration.

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

It is also machine specific encryption which will provide more security.

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines.
It can hidden the connectionStrings but I don't want to dependency asp.net