# unique, non-repeating alphanumeric code based on time ticks

Tags: c#, linq, random

I have the a function I took from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c) which works great:

```
private string GenerateTransactionCode()
{
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                  .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                  .ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

I would like to modify it so that instead of it being random, it picks the alpha numeric digits based on `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`. This way it will be non-repeating. I suppose the characters in the resulting TransactionCode might need to be increased depending on the length of the milliseconds? I would like the length of the resulting TransactionCode to be constant. Hopefully, no more than 8 Characters.

**Example**: If the ticks happened to be `135` (going to me more than that in real life) then the resulting code will be `ACE` or `BDF` depending if it's 0 based (I don't care if it is or not).

Comment: Ticks is not non-repeating... especially on multi-core; however, a simple interlocked counter would be... as would a database `IDENTITY`, and as would be a `Guid` (appropriately constructed, obviously)

Comment: I don't think you want to do this. Modern CPUs are more than capable of doing more than one thing in the resolution of the tick counter. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/3a197913-7d01-415f-a7ff-ba8ff18dae52/) for more information.

Comment: I think your example doesn't represent what you want, in that case only `A` through `J` would be used (unless `135` wasn't a decimal value).

Comment: I was thinking if the ticks were 135 then it would pick it out from the array as such. 135 are the index values of BDF in the chars "array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine what you actually want is a real non-repeating transaction code, or [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier):

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string txcode = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
```

If you want to clean it up:

```
txcode = txcode.Replace("=","").Replace("+","").Replace("/","");
```

Example of generated output is `OEndimZwsEKRAbAwnvzjoA` but because of the replacement of `+` `/` and `=` the length can be slightly unpredictable.

You may prefer this format `g.ToString("N")` which gives something like `58d5381c878b484591568b086296fe8e` and is **guaranteed to be 32 characters long.**

Comment: Will the length be constant? If not, can I make it so?