# Generate random X-length string

Tags: .net

How to create random X-length string that contains letters and numbers. My fast solution is:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(X);
```

Any another better ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "random" strings for dictionary keys, simply use a `Guid`. They will be unique and more than adequate for keying dictionaries.

---

Something like would work, but you need to constrain your random range to avoid shenanigans:

<sub>Warning, coded it and ran it once - otherwise untested. Performance versus your current solution is unquantified. Also, this implementation is a lot wordier than the answer linked in the question comments.</sub>

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int x = r.Next(1, 1000);

        char[] pool = new[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        char[] word = new char[x];

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            // max value is not inclusive, so no -1 from length.
            int a = r.Next(pool.Length); 
            word[i] = pool[a];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string(word));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

There's probably a nicer way to do this using the ASCII codes, but meh.

Answer (score 2):

**GUIDs are not random, they are unique!** If you are using them where randomness is required, you are doing something very wrong.

There are several options for random data generation, but the question here is: *what is it meant for*? Rolling dice? Encrypting state secrets?

Comment: In my case just to generate some random keys for dictionary.

Comment: @DotNETNinja Why not just increment a number or use a Guid as-is?

Comment: @DotNETNinja: Well, since you want keys then you really *do not care* about their values; you only care that they are unique. Not random, just unique. So GUIDs would be a good choice, as would incrementing integers.

Answer (score 1):

I once made a "random" password generator and it looked like this. You can modify it as you please, and there's probably some room for linq expressions here.

```
public static string GeneratePassWord(bool useNumbers,bool useLetters, bool useUpperAndLowerCase, bool useSpecialCharacters, int passwordLength)
{
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    List<char> chars = new List<char>();

    if (useNumbers) // Add numbers
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            chars.Add((char)(48 + i));
        }
    }

    if (useLetters) // Add letters
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) // Small letters
        {
            chars.Add((char)(97 + i));
        }
        if (useUpperAndLowerCase)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) // Large letters
            {
                chars.Add((char)(65 + i));
            }
        }
    }

    if (useSpecialCharacters) // Add specials
    {
        chars.Add((char)'!');
        chars.Add((char)'#');
        chars.Add((char)'%');
        chars.Add((char)'&');
        chars.Add((char)'_');
        chars.Add((char)'.');
        chars.Add((char)'+');
        chars.Add((char)'@');
        chars.Add((char)'$');
    }

    // Generate random password from char
    if (chars.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder newPass = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++)
        {
            newPass.Append(chars[randomNumber.Next(chars.Count)]);
        }
        return newPass.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

As you see, it basically creates a List<> of chars, and then picks randomly from the list for each number of characters you want.