# How to select 5 digit random in C# Array String?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I generate random 8 character, alphanumeric strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c)

I have the array in the name of letters.now i need to select 5 character randomly.If i use the following code i can select only one character.***How to Select the 5 digits in given array string random?***

```
    String[] letters = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q" };
    Random rand = new Random();
    String number = letters[rand.Next(1,10)];
```

Comment: It depends. Do you want to allow the same digit more than once in the selection or you want the 5 chars to be distinct?

Comment: your current code will never select "1", btw. Or any of "A" thru "Q". There are only 9 possible outcomes, from 27 options.

Comment: It would be more efficient to have a `char[]` instead of `string[]`, so that you can avoid multiple string concats for building the final string.

Comment: Or, better yet, a single string: `String letters = "12345..."`

Comment: I hope this isn't for a security purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string number = 
    string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i => 
        letters[rand.Next(0, 10)]));
```

Of course, given your array contents, this is functionally equivalent to:

```
string number = rand.Next(0, 100000).ToString("D5");
```

Comment: The "digits" in the question contain 0-9 and A-Q... neither of the samples shown here actually work!

Comment: The OP used `rand.Next(1,10)` in their sample code; I assume they want 0–9 only, with the rest of the array being irrelevant for the scope of this question.

Comment: hmmm, fair point - I guess that comes down to which part of the question is correct, and which is an error (as written, the question itself is slightly contradictory)

Comment: Yes, on that I agree. Especially since it makes little sense to construct a random five-character string of 0–9 digits manually, when you can get the job much more easier done using `rand` directly.

Comment: Although! If we assume the question is correct, then the OP is **actually** selecting "2" thru "0", not "1" thru "0".

Comment: From "2" to "A" (inclusive), I'm afraid. I assumed that was an error by the OP.

Comment: no, the 10 is exclusive, so it is index 1-thru-9; "A" is not a possible outcome in the original code

Comment: You're right... I had mistakenly assumed the parameters to mean `Random.Next(start,count)` (like for `Enumerable.Range`), instead of `Random.Next(min,max)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] selected = new string[5];
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0 ; i < selected.Length ; i++)
{
    selected[i] = letters[rand.Next(letters.Length)];
}
```

Comment: I'd separate the `new Random()` part from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var randomSelection = (from c in letters orderby rand.Next() select c).Take(5);
```

Comment: Your algorithm never gives the same letter twice. This is more like *suffling*

Comment: Indeed that is the point of the answer. In the question it is not specified if multiple occurences for the same letter are allowed or not. And so far this is the only answer returning a randomly selected distinct set.

Comment: +1: Fair point. The intent of the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Undid the downvote, althought I disagree. `order by` a random data to suffle is also not a good idea.

Comment: @L.B: Why isn't it a good approach for shuffling?

Comment: No it is not good. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/31/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-four.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's true, the current implementation gives inconsistent values each time the sort key is accessed.

Comment: @L.B I think your point is not valid. This is Linq not Sort. Link will query rand.next() for each letter only once and use that as the key for ordering.

Comment: I don't know how you name `OrderBy` but it is a sorting code.

Comment: Of course it is, I just hoped that terminology will better demonstrate what is the difference between what is the linked atticle is about and the current case, and why your point is invalid.

Comment: @L.B: Actually, @Hari is right. I checked the implementation of `Enumerable.OrderBy`; the keys are precomputed and stored in an internal array (through the `EnumerableSorter<TElement,TKey>.ComputeKeys` method) _before_ the sorting commences.