# How secure is Random function in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I'm developing a password generator, which will run on a webpage. 
I'm using the build in features of .net's `Random()`; function in to generate random numbers. They are then used to pick different upper/lower-case characters and numbers from a string.

What I'm wondering is, how secure is it to use `Random()`; function to generate passwords. Note that these passwords expire after 2min, and the page will only allow to generate 3 times per IP adress.

Comment: what excactly do you mean with secure?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to roll your own password generator? You can use the built in [Membership.GeneratePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) method.

Comment: @keyboardP That includes special characters that the user might not be able to type. Trades bad usability for a really small increase of security.

Comment: as a side note use a SecureString not a string to save it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Random` is not secure. The biggest weakness is that it has only a 31 bit seed that's seeded from a predictable source(`Environment.TickCount`). So an attacker who knows when your instance of `Random` was created can probably narrow the possible passwords down to a handful.

The algorithm itself isn't secure either. It's probably possible to predict future outputs from observing a few of them.

Use a class derived from [`System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx), such as [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to generate secure random numbers.

To generate a secure random string, I recommend my answer to [How can I generate random 8 character, alphanumeric strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416143/445517). Note that most other answers there aren't secure.

Comment: Im checking your answers as solution to my problem since it also explained why random() is weak. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `Random` if you need password security.

Use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

> Implements a cryptographic Random Number Generator (RNG) using the implementation provided by the cryptographic service provider (CSP). This class cannot be inherited.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a secure random number, you could write a class which inherits from [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx)