# Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Char

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to implement a random 1 character alphanumeric JArray.

I came across this :

[How can I generate random alphanumeric strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c)

However, I need a JArray so I tried this instead :

```
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = new JArray(
                    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 1)
                                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                                .ToArray());
```

I get a `Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Char` error every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I ask why you accepted the answer that you did?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON Does not have a primitive for characters - only strings, numbers, and arrays. Just add a `.ToString()` to turn your character into a string, which can be converted to a JSON string:

```
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new JArray(
                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 1)
                            .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)].ToString())
                            .ToArray());
```

Comment: +1 for the fact about json not having primitive for characters, but I feel like this doesn't make sense, you shouldn't have to change your character to a string, Json.NET should have a way to convert a character. Maybe someone should bring this up to the project development team as it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Not saying your answer doesn't make sense just that you shouldn't have to do this, the API should deal with this internally.

Comment: @CharlesKeyser I completely agree - I personally consider this a bug with the library - it should automatically do the conversion.

Comment: @TimBJames no worries. I am usually the one bested in the [fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting multiple randoms in sequence may need to change your code to generate better randoms but this will work for creating a JArray

```
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random ( );
    var result = JArray.FromObject (
                Enumerable.Repeat ( chars , 1 )
                            .Select ( s => s [ random.Next ( s.Length ) ] )
                            .ToArray ( ) );
```