# How to generate ALPHANUMERIC Coupon Code in C#?

Tags: c#, random, alphanumeric

I have a method which generates the `Coupon Code`. Can anyone help/ suggest to generate `ALPHANUMERIC CODE`?

Following is the method:

```
public string CouponGenerator(int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * _random.NextDouble() + 65)));

            sb.Append(ch);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
```

**Example:**

*UZWKXQML when Lenght is set to 8*

But it need something like `U6WK8Q2L` i.e Alphanumeric code.

Comment: See [How can I generate random alphanumeric strings in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the length of Coupan code.

```
 var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                  .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                  .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle sequency of alpha bet and take number of chars that you need.

```
   public string CouponGenerator(int length, char[] alphaNumSeed)
    {
        var coupon = alphaNumSeed.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(length);

        return new string(coupon.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: 1) While `NewGuid` is random in the current implementation, it's not guaranteed to be random. 2) Why do you prevent duplicate characters?

Comment: It's just a tricky thing to shuffle char array. And as i know GUID use pseudo-random algorithm, which actually is quite ok, when we are talking about random sequences