# Random String generator with number of alpha and numeric chars C#

Tags: c#, random, stringbuilder

can any help me with random string generator.
I need to generate string with count of numbers and alphacharacters?

now i have this:

```
private static readonly Random Random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    private static string _alphaChars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    private static string _numericChars = "1234567890";
    private static string RandomString(int size, string avaliable)
    {
        var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(x => avaliable[Random.Next(0, avaliable.Length)]);
        return new string(chars.ToArray());
    }
```

but i need change this function to get parameters with count of numeric and alpha, and get string with this count? how i can do this?
I need thay my string contains always, for example: **with 4 alpha chars and 2 numeric.** Count of this thinks must be like parameters

Comment: `with count of numbers and alphacharacters` what does this means ? Do you mean you need a string that is composite of mixture of letters and digits ?

Comment: check below link:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c

Comment: updated my post, look in the end