# Why I am getting 0 in value. I have debugged it and found I am getting 0 in value. Also when i am storing to database it also store 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I am trying to generate random number using RNGCryptoServiceProvider, but some how I am getting o(Zero) in return

```
private int generatePassword()
{

    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        byte[] randomnumber = new byte[10000];
        rng.GetBytes(randomnumber);
       return randomnumber;

    }

}
```

Comment: it is not really clear to me why you call `ToString` on a byte array. It will return the name of the class: `System.Byte[]`. How do you intend to get the value? please describe the thought behind your code

Comment: Your edits aren't helping - you're just producing *uncompilable* code now. Please, instead, take some time, create a [mcve] and [edit] that into your question. Best done in front of a compiler rather than your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should take a look at this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32932758/6876655)

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SsvWY6)

```
static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] uintBuffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];

        while (length-- > 0)
        {
            rng.GetBytes(uintBuffer);
            uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(uintBuffer, 0);
            res.Append(valid[(int)(num % (uint)valid.Length)]);
        }
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```