# Why is this C# console app outputting the same string multiple times?

Tags: c#, string, console, console-application

I'm trying to create a unique code generator and I'm using the solution found here: [How can I generate random alphanumeric strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings)

When I run the app the console outputs the same string 8 times instead of outputting 8 different codes. However if I slow the app down by adding sleep (20ms) between each write then the code outputs 8 different strings.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            string code = GetUniqueCode(8);
            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetUniqueCode(int length)
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var stringChars = new char[length];
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
        }

        var finalString = new String(stringChars);
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it is creating randoms with same seed, because it is creating them too fast

Comment: Bottom line - don't create the `Random` within `GetUniqueCode`.

Comment: Instantiate Random once and not for every 'i' in your loop. You can try declaring Random in your main method and then passing it to GetUniqueCode(int length, Random random).