# Generate random UDID

Tags: c#, uuid, udid

Find this string in HTTP POST request.

```
<UDID>92b690dd7d6c90e10eb3540edf2eedc8b075b8fd</UDID>
```

How can I generate random UDIDs in this format in C#?

Comment: Please at least [show some kind of attempt at figuring this out yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to avoid downvotes.

Comment: See https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/UDID#2007-August_2018 how to calculate a UDID. Basically it's the SHA1 hash of the serial number + IMEI (or empty string if no IMEI) + WiFi MAC address + Bluetooth MAC address.

Comment: Use the answers to [How can I generate random alphanumeric strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1344221/215552) to generate a random string of your desired length and character range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code

```
       var xpto = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

It gives you a GUID without hyphens, what I think should do what you want.

Comment: This generates a GUID with 32 characters, OP's UUID is 40 characters long.

Comment: I see, well yeah, if he needs a 40 char long it wont do.

Comment: @TobiasTengler - out of curiosity, you didn't actually count the characters of OPs UDID, or did you?

Comment: @RandRandom thats not difficult if you put the string on notepad++

Comment: @RandRandom nope, I used a [Chrome Extension](https://imgur.com/XFTCKmU) that shows me the character count of highlighted text.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim - `Guid`'s do not have a guarantee of being random, only unique. You should never assume randomness in a Guid.