# Can I use the RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32() method to generate a cryptographically-secure random string?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, random, cryptography

I've been trying to write a simple helper method in C# that generates a cryptographically-secure random string with any given length and character set. I know that you shouldn't use the [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0) class if you want cryptographic security. In the past, the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=net-6.0) class would always be suggested as an alternative to `Random` to provide cryptographic safety. That class is now obsolete and [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator) is supposed to be used instead.

Now, what I'm confused about is that many answers in [this famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1344221/7734384) that are using the new `RandomNumberGenerator` class — such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344255/7734384) — are using the `GetBytes()` method, and then doing lots of other stuff afterwards to make things work; but I don't understand why they're not using [`GetInt32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getint32?view=netcore-3.0) instead and then using the result as an index in the character set? It seems like that would make this much simpler.

This is what I'm talking about:

```
public string GenerateRandomString(int length, string charSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
{
    char[] result = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = charSet[RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(charSet.Length)];

    return new string(result);
}
```

My question is this: **Is this way of generating random strings cryptographically sound or not?** The fact that I never saw this being done makes me uncertain, which is why I'm asking this question. And if it isn't, could you please explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use `GetBytes` and then use the result to generate the string. When I need a random string, I generally don't care about string length, I care about entropy. So I just use GetBytes and convert it to a hex string. If you want to use an arbitrary character set, you could use GetBytes and then figure the length of the character set. If <16, use each nibble (with a modulus operation) to index into the character set. If >=16 and <256, use each byte, same with 64k and each 16 bit int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation you have linked:

> Cryptographic random number generators create cryptographically strong random values.

Okay, let's now look at `GetInt32`:

> Generates a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and a specified exclusive upper bound **using a cryptographically strong random number generator**.

(emphasis mine)

Most importantly, it later on states:

> This method uses a discard-and-retry strategy to avoid the low value bias that a simple modular arithmetic operation would produce.

So it can be used to reliably produce a random string, yes.

As for the reasoning, well, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` did not have `GetInt32`, it only had `GetBytes`, so of course old code that used to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` and was then hastily modified to use `RandomNumberGenerator` instead to fix the obsolete warning won't use the new method.

Comment: So the answer is yes? I actually read that part of the documentation, I understand that it means that the numbers `GetInt32` generates are in fact cryptographically-secure, but I don't know **if that means that random strings generated using `GetInt32` in this manner (in my code snippet)** would also be cryptographically-secure?

Comment: Yeah, picking a random number and using that as index is cryptographically secure, **assuming** you want to have a normal distribution of character values. This is not always the case (e.g. password generators that require you to at least have one symbol).