# Randomize userinputfield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to create a script where the user can make inputfields and the add data to it and a other screen the name will be randomized on every click you do.

```
public void StoreName()
{
    foreach (var input in inputFields)
    {
        string name = input.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        names.Add(name);
    }
    string result = "";
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        result += name + "\n";
    }
    textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to generate a random string with a specific length

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

this may be useful for more informations

[How can I generate random alphanumeric strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings)