# Tcl dict unset order of complexity

Tags: dictionary, tcl, time-complexity

If I am doing dict unset, what is the average order of complexity?
 I am really crossing my fingers for O(1).
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's `dict` is internally implemented as a hashtable. The command:

> `dict unset` removes a key and its associated value from a dictionary of dictionaries.

Therefore it is in worst case `O(n)`.
With an average of `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i have guessed and hoped for, but could not be certain of.

Comment: Possibly of interest to readers of this answer: [Hash table runtime complexity (insert, search and delete)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214353/hash-table-runtime-complexity-insert-search-and-delete)

Comment: You'd only get O(n) with very carefully crafted dictionaries. You can use `dict info` to analyse the time to look up a key and its entry. (There is, of course, a constant amount of work to delete the entry once it has been found.)