# Time complexity of Swift's Set.indexOf

Tags: swift, set, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of `Set.indexOf`? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Set/s:FVs3Set7indexOfFxGSqGVs8SetIndexx__) doesn't say, and the [source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-2.2-branch/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L365) delegates to some kind of internal storage class (`_VariantStorage`/`_VariantSetStorage`) whose source I can't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FesRxs14CollectionTypeWx9Generator7Element_s9EquatablerS_7indexOfFWxS0_S1__GSqwx5Index_) for `CollectionType` suggests that it is O(self.count).

That would make sense, as the worst case scenario is that every element in the `Set` (or any other collection) is checked for equality. It shouldn't ever be *more* complex than O(self.count).

Comment: That applies to the default implementation, but `Set` provides its own. And depending on how `Set.Index` works, it would make sense for `Set` to be able to provide an `O(1)` implementation, since the whole point of sets is constant-time lookup.

Comment: Take a look at this answer regarding complexity of hash tables generally which suggests that indeed O(n) is worst case scenario, with O(1) being possible, but not guaranteed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214353/hash-table-runtime-complexity-insert-search-and-delete

Comment: After more research, I found that the source for `_VariantSetStorage` is actually in the same file; I just didn't find it with Search because of the GYB macro stuff. Based on that, I believe that while your answer is technically correct, a more thorough version would be: `O(1)` average for a native `Set`, `O(n)` average for a wrapped `NSSet`, and `O(n)` worst-case for both (due to hash collisions).