# Find 3 elements in sorted array that sum up to 0 (a+b+c = 0)

Tags: algorithm

Is there any better solution than the obvious O(n^3)? I can use one element multiple times so for an array {-1, 0, 2} there is a solution: (-1, -1, 2) or (0, 0, 0).

Comment: iterate all sum pairs then check if that sum * -1 is in your array.  O(n^2) solution

Comment: @juvian isn't this log(n) * n^2 ? (log(n) because you search the array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [O(NlogN) finding 3 numbers that have a sum of any arbitrary T in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861516/onlogn-finding-3-numbers-that-have-a-sum-of-any-arbitrary-t-in-an-array)

Comment: This can be done in `O(n^2)`. You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210351/find-if-there-are-elements-x-y-z-in-unsorted-array-so-that-x-y-z), but there the question was to see `x + y = z`, in your case `z` would be `-(x+y)`.

Comment: Not if you search with a hashtable

Answer (score 0):

The classic [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) problem can be solved in O(n^2). This can also be solved with O(n^2)

```
# assume arr is sorted and doesn't contain duplicates

out = []
s = set(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i, len(arr)):
        a = - (arr[i] + arr[j])
        if a >= arr[j] and a in s:
            out.append((arr[i], arr[j], a))
```

Comment: I do not understand the two sentences together.

Comment: can you give an example where this fails?