# How do i go on to reduce HashTable worst case run time complexity?

Tags: java, hash, time-complexity, runtime, hashtable

If i am trying to do a lookup or insert then how do i ensure that it has a O(log n) worst case instead of O(n)?

I have tried to look it up and apparently the solution to this is to sort the values but it seems like you can not sort a hash table without increasing the complexity which is not what i am hoping for.

Language is Java.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214353/hash-table-runtime-complexity-insert-search-and-delete)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.